# echo scores per month even if month has no data

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am stumped by a pretty basic problem here.
I have a table with columns `month` and `score` which I need to populate in JS for a chart display.

```
$sql = "SELECT `med_month`, `med_score` FROM `charts_data_table`";


med_month, med_score
1, 11.1
2, 22,2
3, 33
4, 44,4
5, 55.5
6, 66
7, 77
8, 88
9, 99
10, 101
```

The issue now is that I have as of right now 10 months of data (missing Nov and Dec) which are not part of the query result.

How can I echo each months score for the records I have on file, while either omitting future months, resp. setting them with a score of `0.00`?

Preferred output:

```
labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
data: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 0.00, 0.00]
```

**EDIT**

There seems to be a lot of confusion and wrong focus on my query instead of what I am actually asking here. I would like to know, how can `echo` the above table data **in PHP** in the the **preferred output format** above.

The query is fine and does no need amending, its merely the steps of:

- converting month number to `MMM` format (eg. `date_format()` in PHP)
- output of month / score in `$val.', '` format

that I need help with, since JS needs me to provide 12 values but I at the moment only have 10.

Comment: your question needs little more bit explanation for reader

Comment: @TarangP  Edited, thank you.

Comment: please  share us your sql

Comment: Just make a loop in php, and parse the results inside that.

Answer (score 1):

You need  a months list 
a simple way is add the missing month in query using UNION

```
$sql = "SELECT `med_month`, `med_score` 
        FROM `charts_data_table`
        UNION 
        select 11, 0
        union 
        select 12,0";
```

or create and use a month table with 12 values in join

```
$sql = "SELECT `med_month`, ifnull(c.`med_score` , 0)
        MONTH_TABLE m 
        LEFT JOIN  `charts_data_table` c on m.nonth = c.med_month";
```

Another simple way is based on prepoulation with 0 
Assuming you have an array for month

$month = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

```
for ($x = 0; $x<12; $++) {
    $chart_month[$x] = $month[$x];
    $chart_score = 0;
}

... 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $chart_month = $row['med_month'];
    $chart_score = $row['med_score'];
 ... .

}
```

Comment: the issue is not the SQL query, my results are correct. I can always `date_format` the month number into a `MMM` format, which IMO is simpler. My problem is the output and how can I set the monthly score to `0` there.

Comment: IMO the simplest way is obatin the values direcly form the query  . .. otherwise yiu should change you loop for manager 12 months  .. (and not the query result) .

Comment: I understand that, but as I said my query values are not the problem. My question specifically is how to `echo` the result in the preferred output.

Comment: This first option seems like an odd way of going about it, given that the second option is available

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(id, '%m')),IFNULL(sum(med_score),0) as score
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 3 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 4 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 5 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 6 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 7 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 8 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 9 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 10 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 11 AS ID 
        UNION 
        SELECT 12 AS ID) AS Months 
       LEFT JOIN `charts_data_table` 
              ON Months.id = `charts_data_table`.med_month 
GROUP  BY Months.id 
ORDER  BY Months.id ASC
```

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/334766/select-query-to-results-all-12-months-even-if-data-not-exist

Build a reference table with all month names and left join it to your data table.